# How to disable multi-line indenting in fish shell CLI?

Tags: shell, indentation, fish

When I enter multi-line commands, fish indents it like this:

[image: before]

I'd like it to start new line from the begining (first terminal column). After pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> on the first line, it should look like this:

[image: after]

Is it possible? Is there an option to set fish behave this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do this in the command-line editor.

You might like to use a full-featured editor by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>.